# how to make header image at center in using css?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

could you please tell me how to make logo at center in using css.Actually I am using `media` query for `mobile` view .In desktop my html is working fine , but in mobile view
I want to show `logo` on center and have two `menu` option side by side (see below image).

here is my code

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (min-width:320px) {
    .header{
        background: #00B7FF;
        flex-direction: column;

    }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-wcvzbw?file=style.css

[image]

Comment: You need to create a minimal example of your code here. Not in an external link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the container width to 100%.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .container {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
```

And then align the header to center.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .header{
     text-align: center;
  }
}
```

You can see the example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-95nsut?file=style.css).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to center it vertically, adding `margin: auto;` should do the trick in a flex column layout.